# Why there is no if-constexpr for global (out-of-function) scope in C++?

Tags: c++, if-constexpr

Is there any special reason why `if constexpr` can't be used outside function's body (why it is not implemented in C++)? For example like in code below that uses `if constexpr` to decide what specializations of sub-class to make:

```
template <int Size>
struct A {
    template <typename T> struct B;

    if constexpr(Size >= 32) {
        template <> struct B<uint32_t> {};
    }
    if constexpr(Size == 32) {
        using MaxT = uint32_t;
    }
    if constexpr(Size >= 64) {
        template <> struct B<uint64_t> {};
    }
    if constexpr(Size == 64) {
        using MaxT = uint64_t;
    }
};
```

That syntax above is much more handy than using [std::enable_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) and [std::conditional_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) and other tricks.

Syntax above allows to generate any code based on value of compile time constant. And would be a great replacement for `#ifdef`/`#endif` macros in many cases.

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67915638/why-there-is-no-if-constexpr-for-global-out-of-function-scope-in-c?#comment120042282_67915638) by @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, there exists similar concept in other languages like [static if in D](https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2019/01/15/if-constexpr-isnt-broken/).

Does anyone know if there were any proposals regarding this syntax and any future plans? If they were rejected then why?

Comment: You mean like `static if` in D? https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2019/01/15/if-constexpr-isnt-broken/

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Yes, exactly.

Comment: That was the *original* proposal. The lack of introducing scope didn't sit well with the voting members. Seeing as this is the refined result, I don't think anyone plans on changing anything.